# Measure value from different level

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube

I have something like this:

scope 1:

```
Facility desc | Line Quantity In
a | 5
b | 6
c | 7
```

scope 2:

```
Facility desc | Production Line Desc | Line Quantity In
a | ax | 5
a | ay | null
a | az | null
b | bb | 6
c | c  | 7


CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Facility QIn]
AS(  
([Measures].[Line Quantity In],  [DIM RESOURCE].[Production Line Desc]. [All])
)
,
FORMAT_STRING = "# ##0,00%;-# ##0,00%",
VISIBLE = 1 , ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'x';
```

I built Line Quantity In using scopes, the null value is correct because Production Lines ax, ay, az are not having some flag set to True
But in several situations I must get Line Quantity In from Facility level
it should look like this:

```
a | ax | 5
a | ay | 5
a | az | 5
b | bb | 6
c | c  | 7
```

Is this possible?

Comment: currently i'm using Parant function, but i am getting nulls while browsing additional columns :(

Comment: Do you have the code including the use of `.Parent` function?

Comment: ok i found the solution using scopes

Comment: Good. You can add answer to your own question if you like.